# I am integrating the paypal sandbox. but my sandbox payment page getting blank with genericError?code=UEFZTUVOVF9ERU5JRUQ%3D

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

After click on pay now button on my website my page redirect to sandbox.paypal.com page. i login with personal paypal sandbox account to pay and come back to my website with success or fail message.
But paypal page getting blank with https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/checkoutweb/genericError?code=UEFZTUVOVF9ERU5JRUQ%3D&cancelLink=&merchantName=

Before coming above url below given screen are coming.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZ2Cj.png)

Anyone Please help
Thanks

Comment: Provide details about your integration

Comment: i have edited my question with image. do you need sandbox account credentials?

Answer (score 0):

Due to local regulations, PayPal support for INR and domestic payments in India was removed 1 April 2020.

List of currently supported currency codes (for international payments): https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/develop/currency-codes/#paypal-account-payments

At least one party to the transaction must be an account that is not from India.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, `UEFZTUVOVF9ERU5JRUQ` is base64 for `PAYMENT_DENIED`

Comment: Why do they make the error code this obfuscated base64 instead of just saying payment denied?